Why can I read 360k 5.25" floppies on a High-Density drive but not mid-sized disks?
I can apparently read 360K disks from my high-density 5.25" floppy drive. But I don't think it works for 720K disk.
Currently I'm using a 2-in-one drive (has a 3.5in laptop drive in same half-height case) attached to an FC5025 USB floppy controller.  This will even read a 360k disk when I tell it to read a 1.2m high-density disk. But, I don't remember having to use different drives for 360k disks on the old family DOS system.  And the collection of disks from that system are a semi-random mix of 360k and High Density disks.
Is there a technical reason that it was possible to use the same drive for both the low-capacity and high-density formats but couldn't use it for an in-between size?  Was there just no in-between size like there was for 3.5" (double-sided double-density)?

The way it is written the question doesn't make much sense. It feels a bit like several terms have been messed up. I would think by 370k you mean 360 KiB, right? Also, I assume 'high density' is supposed to mean 1200 KiB type disks, true? Finally, since 360 KiB disks are already double density (at 40 tracks), the question would only make sense if your double-density is about 640k or 720 KiB (80 track) disks - right? In that case the answer would be it depends on which of those and what controller is used. 720 will work on 1.2, 640 only if the data clock or RPM can be switched.

Further the FC5025 is an unusal beast which should be able to read at 250 (DD) and 300 (HD) kbps in 40 and 80 track, so all formats you (may) mention above, but that all depends on drivers and software. Better check the [its supplier's pages[(http://www.deviceside.com/fc5025.html).

Assuming you're talking about reading quad density 5.25" disks, and assuming you're trying to do it with a HD floppy drive, the issue is likely that most standard quad density drives operate at 300 rpm instead of the normal 360 rpm. You'll likely need a HD floppy drive that has a jumper on it to set the motor to 300 rpm operation.

@Raffzahn I thought I remembered classic floppies being 370k, I'll correct that.

@mnem This is probably an actual answer.  If the the in-between size used a different spindle speed then it wouldn't be compatible without a way to change that.  I think my drive may have those jumpers, but I don't think our old drives did in the day.

Was there a 720k-ish disk for 5.25" ?  If not I will have to heavily modify the question to just be: why could a High-Density 5.25" floppy drive read 'low-density' disks without any problem?

There are actually a surprising number of different high density 5.25" floppy drives from various manufacturers that support being jumpered to the lower spindle speed albeit to widely varying degrees of how well labelled / documented those options are on the drive circuit board and the fact that a lot of them are just implemented as solder bridge jumpers, not actual pin headers.

It's probably worth noting that "quad density" 5.25" floppies were never really much of a thing on PCs. It was something that was mostly used on other oddball home computers, not PC compatibles. The most common place I've encountered them (HD drives jumpered to function as quad density drives) was "80 track" 5.25" drives for Amigas which even there was a pretty niche 3rd party option, mostly confined to price sensitive markets. They appeared to the computer as indistinguishable from a standard DD 3.5" drive so allowed use of cheaper 5.25" media in a transparent fashion.
